# Making kernel object with make ARCH=i386

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel, kernel

I have a file named dice_driver.c that I would like to make a .ko file out of it. Here's my Makefile:

```
obj-m := dice_driver.o
KDIR  := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD   := $(shell pwd)
default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
```

However, when I entered make ARCH=i386 into my VM on VirtualBox, as per my instructor's guidance, it says

```
make: Nothing to be done for 'default'.
```

Could anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: According to error message, it looks like you use *spaces* instead of **tabulation** for ident the last line.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks so much, I fixed the problem!